# Stern-Gerlach: would QED treat it as many discrete virtual-photon interactions?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, measurements

If yes, how many? And in the region of few interactions, does that correspond to a “weak measurement”?

(I come to this question while learning about decoherence. We usually think of entanglement for one or a few particles. We think of a measurement as involving an amplification. Would a large number N of virtual interactions, be a kind of avalanche, where a “pen balanced on its tip” (potential for different outcomes) pushes the pen in one direction (spin-up or spin-down), while only a few gives overlapping up/down patches and thus an inconclusive (weak) measurement? Is a measurement the large-N limit with a threshold where there is no overlap?)

Comment: Why virtual? The magnetic field applied is real. Look up euler heisenberg effective lagrangian or the particle propagator in a background field which is closer to the experiment

Comment: @lux, The classical magnetic field is continuous, while interaction with virtual photons is a set of discrete events. I'm curious about the difference in analysis.

Comment: Sure, a fundamental treatment would ask for a full qft description. At the level of the SG exp, with low energies and weakly varying field you can treat the field as semiclasscal

Comment: In the original Stern-Gerlach experiment, a beam of silver atoms comes out of the stove with a temperature of about 1300C. It is amazing how they managed to measure the quantum effect there. To describe the dynamics of particles, they still use classic mechanics with the quantization condition for the magnetic moment $\mu=\pm \mu_B$. QED is for particles with a temperature close to zero. Perhaps for these problems https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.96.053630